# Find the inverse and use it to solve

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is the problem: In $\mathbb{Z}_{35}$, find the inverse of $\overline{13}$ and use it to solve $\overline{13}x=\overline{9}$.

What I've done:
The inverse exists as gcd(35,13)=1. The euclidean algorithm gives
35=2(13)+9
13=1(9)+4
9=2(4)+1
so, eventually 1=3(35)-8(13). Thus, $8(13)\equiv$ 1 (mod 35) and $\overline{8}$ is the inverse of $\overline{13}$. BUT, the answer key says that $\overline{27}$ is the inverse and I don't see how.

And then I'm not sure how to solve for the equation given with the said inverse.

Comment: Note that you have $1=3(35)+(-8)(13)$, so $-8$ is the inverse (you found this correctly, only misinterpreted the results).

Comment: Gottchaa. And easy mistake on my part. 
And then to solve $\overline{13}$x=$\overline{9}$ I get $\overline{-8}$*$\overline{13}$x=$\overline{-8}$*$\overline{9}$. And then my x equals a decimal number which isn't correct.

Comment: I would suggest you take another look at what it means for elements to be equal in modular arithmetic; there appears to be a fundamental misunderstanding you have based on the comments below rschwieb's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You found that $-8$ is the inverse, not $8$. $-8\equiv 27 \pmod {35}$.

$8\cdot 13 \equiv-1\equiv 34\pmod {35}$.

To solve the equation, you proceed exactly as you do in basic algebra. You multiply both sides with $13^{-1}$ and reduce.

Comment: So is -8 or 27 the inverse?

Comment: Since $27+8=35$, $-8$ and $27$ are the same mod $35$!

Comment: @ematth7 *both* are... They are *equal*.

Comment: Ohh okay.  
And then to solve $\overline{13}$x=$\overline{9}$ I get $\overline{-8}$*$\overline{13}$x=$\overline{-8}$*$\overline{9}$. And then my x equals a decimal number which isn't correct.

Comment: @ematth7 why do you think $(-8)9\pmod {35}$ is a decimal? (it isn't)

Comment: @rschwieb My textbook said to multiply both sides of $\overline{13}x=\overline{9}$ by the inverse, so $\overline{-8}$. So I would have -65x=72, so x would be a decimal.

Comment: @ematth7 It doesn't look like you're grasping how modular arithmetic works. Both $-8\cdot 13=-104$ and $-8\cdot 9=-72$ reduce mod 35. The whole reason you picked $-8$ is because $-104\equiv 1\pmod{35}$. On the other reduction, $-72=-72+2(35)=-2=-2+35=33\pmod{35}$. Your equation changes, then, into $x=33\pmod{35}$

Answer (score 0):

Your steps are correct and you have found a solution to the equation $35x+13y=1$ which is $x=3$, $y=-8$. So the inverse of $13$ mod $35$ is $-8\equiv-8+35\equiv 27 \text{ (mod }35 \text{)}$. Now to solve the equation you multiply by $-8$ on both sides as this will cancel out the $x$ coefficient:

$$
\begin{split} &&13x=9 \text{ (mod }35 \text{)} \\ &\implies& -8\cdot 13x=-8\cdot 9 \text{ (mod }35\text{)} \\ &\implies& -104x=-72\text{ (mod }35\text{)} \\ &\implies& x=-72 \text{ (mod }35\text{)} \\ &\implies& x=33 \text{ (mod }35\text{)}  \end{split}
$$

Note in the solution that $-104\equiv 1$ (mod $35$) (and this shouldn't be surprising as that was the whole point of using the Euclidean algorithm to find $13^{-1}$ (mod $35$)) and $-72\equiv 33$ (mod $35$).